# Reverse engineering a black box's random generator

Tags: statistics

The title isn't ideal, sorry. If this question isn't appropriate for math exchange, please guide me to a better one.

There's a loaded coin that land heads or tails, but they aren't distributed equally. We have unlimited access to using it, and we have to figure out the internal probability table from just the results.

How many times would we have to record the outcome to be sure we aren't too off from the actual truth? How would we even describe our confidence level?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair

Comment: @MattiP. I wasn't aware of that article, thank you. How would one approach this if there were more than 2 values?